# get AWS region for describeImages

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Im trying to get all Ami images using below code using python 2.7 in AWS lambda

result = client.describe_images(
        Owners=[
            'self'
        ]
    )

Im able to get the ami images but not able to get in  which region its created...i would like to filter images based on region.Please suggest

Comment: You can get the region for image using "ec2-describe-images <ami-id>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with the AWS EC2 SDK, you are only working in a single region.

So by calling `client.describe_images()`, you are already filtered to a single region. All AMI images returned in the result are in that same region.

To get all AMI images in all regions, then you need to iterate across all regions, calling `client.describe_images()` within each region.